# When dropout is useful for segmentation task?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I am working in segmentation task. I have a small number of the dataset. My network is very deep (Resnet-based). My question is that when dropout is useful in my field? I know that dropout often uses to handle with overfitting problem. But for segmentation, I did not see many papers using dropout. Thanks